# Error after upgrading to JDK 8 on Tomcat

Tags: java

Here's the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\FMIS2_TEST\FMIS_APP\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\fmis2\WEB-INF\classes\com\evnit\fmis\viewmodel\accounting\TongHopDuLieuVM$DoiTuongComparator.class];
>
> nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51966
>       Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml];
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\FMIS2_TEST\FMIS_APP\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\fmis2\WEB-INF\classes\com\evnit\fmis\viewmodel\accounting\TongHopDuLieuVM$DoiTuongComparator.class];
>
> nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51966

Here's the code

```
public class DoiTuongComparator implements
        Comparator<KiemTraTongHopDoiTuongBean>,
        GroupComparator<KiemTraTongHopDoiTuongBean>, Serializable {

    @Override
    public int compareGroup(KiemTraTongHopDoiTuongBean arg0,
            KiemTraTongHopDoiTuongBean arg1) {
        if (arg0.getCheckGroup().equals(arg1.getCheckGroup()))
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(KiemTraTongHopDoiTuongBean o1,
            KiemTraTongHopDoiTuongBean o2) {
        return o1.getCheckGroup().compareTo(o2.getCheckGroup().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: since you're not using any array in this class this question belongs to superuser.com - its a platform specific JDK migration problem, which is a systems administration topic at its finest.

Comment: This class should be a static nested class, instead of being a non-static inner class. Which version of Spring are you using? What's the full stack trace of the exception?